# pandas installation failed with Error "ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas" from setup.py

Tags: pandas, setuptools, packaging, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm tying to build a package which required pandas, numpy and scikit-learn as dependency. so i have added the dependencies in my setup.py as below.

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='dest',
    version='0.0.18',
    author="Manikandan Jeyabal",
    author_email="ManikandanJeyabal029@gmail.com",
    description="Test Project creation",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "numpy <=1.17.4", "pandas", "scikit-learn >= 0.21.3, <= 0.22"
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7'
 )
```

but unfortunately pandas installation failed with error for below cases
1) "pandas" -> `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas`
2) "pandas == 0.25.3" -> `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==0.25.3`
3) "pandas >=0.25, <=1.0.0" -> `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas>=0.25, <=1.0.0`

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Regards,
MJ

Comment: OS? Python version? `pip` version? 32- or 64-bit Python? Can you install any package with `pip install`? Try `pip install -vvv pandas` and show the logs.

Comment: @phd,  i'm trying to build an package for DS/ML where i need to add few dependencies for my package where i need to add in install_requires. it is failing at this phase.

Comment: If you're using test.pypi, that might be the issue since the packages there are for only testing. Try to install pandas first, then test your package from test.pypi.

Comment: Same here. Everything was working fine with the same setup about a week ago. When I tried to recreate my virtual environment I started to get this error ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.2.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.2.0```

Comment: When I try `pip install pandas` I get version 1.1.5. But it doesn't allow me to install pandas 1.2.0